# Is it possible to actually make async rest calls?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

I need to make some async rest calls in a way that works in 2.7 and 3.x. I've seen some suggestions for grequests, but the documentation is pretty lacking. My default code looks like this:

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 10):        
    x = requests.post('some_endpoint', data={"a":i})
```

Works fine but isn't async. I tried using grequests, but the only usage i've found looks like this:

```
import grequests

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = grequests.post('some_endpoint', data={"a":i})
    grequests.map([x])
```

and this works, but its not acting async.

Am I doing something wrong, or does grequests not behave the way I was assuming? Is there some other library I can use that will work in 2.7 and 3.x?

Comment: regardless of the behavior of grequests, you're making 10 not-asynchronous calls to make_request.

Comment: Removed the call to make_request. Still not getting async behavior.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking

Comment: How do you detect it's not acting async? Does `some_endpoint` have enough of a delay so that you can several requests being made before the first request is answered?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send all your requests at once using `grequests.map` as it won't return until all the requests are complete.

```
import grequests

req = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    req.append(grequests.get('https://www.google.com'))

grequests.map(req)
for r in req:
    print r.response
```